# How should DetectCondition be specified for a Burn bundle ExePackage?

Tags: wix, burn

In my bundle, I am chaining another burn bundle as an ExePackage.

```
<ExePackage SourceFile="$(var.DatabaseBundle.TargetPath)"
            InstallCommand="/install /quiet"
            UninstallCommand="/uninstall /quiet"
            Protocol="burn"
            PerMachine="yes" />
```

When uninstalling, the burn log shows that DatabaseBundle is absent, so it will not be uninstalled. So obviously, I need to set `DetectCondition` to something so that it is properly detected.

Is there a feature of the Burn bundle that can be conveniently detected, or should I search for an underlying msi product/component/etc using the WixUtilExtension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's nothing built-in to detect bundles. There's an [open bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/wix/bugs/3014/) to make that happen.